# Universal Family in the stack of principal bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

I have read that a stack can just be thought of as a solution to a moduli problem, and there are some examples, like the stack of elliptic curves or the stack of vector bundles over a scheme $X$ such that there exists a universal family. Is there any criterion to know if given a stack there exists a universal family on it? More precisely, what happens with the stack of principal bundles over a curve? Does it carry a universal family?

Comment: Roughly, stacks are built up by gluing together the bases of all families $X \to B$ of whatever type (let's say genus $g$ curves over $\mathbb C$ to be concrete) by this equivalence relation: if $X \to B$ and $X' \to B'$ are two families of this type, we identify $b \in B$ and $b' \in B'$ iff there is an isomorphism between the fibers $X_b \cong X_{b'}'$. The stackiness arises because this equivalence relation is often not something as nice as gluing an open set to an open set, so you don't just get a scheme. But anyway, this means that the universal family is "hardwired" into the definition.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @TabesBridges, I know the motivation for the theory of stacks as well as its definitions but, I don't understand what some authors called  universal family and how it is implicit in the definition of stack. For schemes is clear.